# Qt 5.11 - QML - show XML file in treeView as QAbstractItemModel

Tags: c++, qt, qml, treeview, qabstractitemmodel

I'm trying to show a simple XML file in a QML treeView through the QAbstractItemModel class, but I can't find any decent tutorial on how to do so online. The best I managed to find is a tutorial about how to do it in QWidget, but I want to do it in QML. I tried anyway with all the bits I could find here and there but couldn't even manage to get a tree to show up.

Code compiles, but my model is null. I'm not even sure if I'm actually reading my XML file.

There's very likely a lot of things I am missing or doing wrong. Can anyone help ?

**DomItem.h**

```
#ifndef DOMITEM_H
#define DOMITEM_H
#include <QDomNode>
#include <QHash>

class DomItem
{
    public:
        DomItem(const QDomNode &node, int row, DomItem *parent = nullptr);
        ~DomItem();
        DomItem *child(int i);
        DomItem *parent();
        QDomNode node() const;
        int row() const;

    private:
        QDomNode domNode;
        QHash<int, DomItem *> childItems;
        DomItem *parentItem;
        int rowNumber;
};

#endif // DOMITEM_H
```

**DomItem.cpp**

```
#include "DomItem.h"

DomItem::DomItem(const QDomNode &node, int row, DomItem *parent)
    : domNode(node),
      parentItem(parent),
      rowNumber(row)
{

}

DomItem::~DomItem()
{
    qDeleteAll(childItems);
}

DomItem *DomItem::parent()
{
    return parentItem;
}

int DomItem::row() const
{
    return rowNumber;
}

QDomNode DomItem::node() const
{
    return domNode;
}

DomItem *DomItem::child(int i)
{
    DomItem *childItem = childItems.value(i);
    if (childItem)
        return childItem;

    // if child does not yet exist, create it
    if (i >= 0 && i < domNode.childNodes().count()) {
        QDomNode childNode = domNode.childNodes().item(i);
        childItem = new DomItem(childNode, i, this);
        childItems[i] = childItem;
    }
    return childItem;
}
```

**DomModel.h**

```
#ifndef DOMMODEL_H
#define DOMMODEL_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QModelIndex>
#include <QAbstractItemModel>
#include <QDomDocument>
#include <QFile>
#include "DomItem.h"

class DomModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        enum DomModelRoles
        {
            DomModelRoleName = Qt::UserRole + 1,
            DomModelRoleAttributes,
            DomModelRoleValue
        };

        explicit DomModel(const QDomDocument &document, QObject *parent = nullptr);
        ~DomModel();

        QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;
        Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const override;
        QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
                            int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
        QModelIndex index(int row, int column,
                          const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
        QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &child) const override;
        int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
        int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
        void loadXml(QString xmlFilePath);
        void reload();
         QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override;

    private:
        QDomDocument domDocument;
        DomItem *rootItem;
        QString xmlSource;
};

#endif // DOMMODEL_H
```

**DomModel.cpp**

```
#include "DomModel.h"

DomModel::DomModel(const QDomDocument &document, QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractItemModel(parent),
      domDocument(document)
{
    rootItem = new DomItem(domDocument, 0);
    
}

DomModel::~DomModel()
{
    delete rootItem;
}

int DomModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return 3;
}

Qt::ItemFlags DomModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return Qt::NoItemFlags;

    return QAbstractItemModel::flags(index);
}

QVariant DomModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
                              int role) const
{
    if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal && role == Qt::DisplayRole) {
        switch (section) {
            case 0:
                return tr("Name");
            case 1:
                return tr("Attributes");
            case 2:
                return tr("Value");
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return QVariant();
}

QModelIndex DomModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (!hasIndex(row, column, parent))
        return QModelIndex();

    DomItem *parentItem;

    if (!parent.isValid())
        parentItem = rootItem;
    else
        parentItem = static_cast<DomItem*>(parent.internalPointer());

    DomItem *childItem = parentItem->child(row);
    if (childItem)
        return createIndex(row, column, childItem);
    return QModelIndex();
}

int DomModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (parent.column() > 0)
        return 0;

    DomItem *parentItem;

    if (!parent.isValid())
        parentItem = rootItem;
    else
        parentItem = static_cast<DomItem*>(parent.internalPointer());

    return parentItem->node().childNodes().count();
}

QModelIndex DomModel::parent(const QModelIndex &child) const
{
    if (!child.isValid())
        return QModelIndex();

    DomItem *childItem = static_cast<DomItem*>(child.internalPointer());
    DomItem *parentItem = childItem->parent();

    if (!parentItem || parentItem == rootItem)
        return QModelIndex();

    return createIndex(parentItem->row(), 0, parentItem);
}

QVariant DomModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    if (role != Qt::DisplayRole)
        return QVariant();

    const DomItem *item = static_cast<DomItem*>(index.internalPointer());
    const QDomNode node = item->node();

    switch (role)
    {
        case DomModelRoleName:
            return node.nodeName();

        case DomModelRoleAttributes:
        {
            const QDomNamedNodeMap attributeMap = node.attributes();
            QStringList attributes;
            for (int i = 0; i < attributeMap.count(); ++i) {
                QDomNode attribute = attributeMap.item(i);
                attributes << attribute.nodeName() + "=\""
                              + attribute.nodeValue() + '"';
            }
            return attributes.join(' ');
        }

        case DomModelRoleValue:
            return node.nodeValue().split('\n').join(' ');

        default:
            break;
    }
    return QVariant();
}

void DomModel::loadXml(QString xmlFilePath)
{
    xmlFilePath.replace("file:///","");
    // on parse le xml de l'environnement
    QFile file(xmlFilePath);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly| QFile::Text)){
        //QMessageBox::critical(this, "ParserFichierXML", "Error");
    }
    else{
        domDocument.clear();
        if (!domDocument.setContent(&file)) {
            //QMessageBox::critical(this, "ParserFichierXML", "Error");
        }
        file.close();
    }
    reload();
}

void DomModel::reload()
{
    beginResetModel();
    delete rootItem;
    rootItem = new DomItem(domDocument, 0,false);
    endResetModel();
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> DomModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[DomModelRoleName] = "Name";
    roles[DomModelRoleAttributes] = "Attributes";
    roles[DomModelRoleValue] = "Value";
    return roles;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QDomDocument>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "DomModel.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);

    QQmlContext *ctx = engine.rootContext();

    QFile file("./test.xml");
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QDomDocument document;
        if (document.setContent(&file))
        {
            DomModel *model = new DomModel(document);
             ctx->setContextProperty("theModel", model);
        }

    }
    file.close();
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtLocation 5.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQml 2.0

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    TreeView
    {
        id:treeView
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: theModel
        itemDelegate: TreeDelegate
        {
            id: treeDeleg
        }
        style: TreeViewStyle
        {
            id: styleTree
        }

        TableViewColumn
        {
            id:column1
            role: "Name"
            title: "Name"
            width: 450
        }
        TableViewColumn
        {
            id:column3
            role: "Value"
            title: "Value"
            width: 400
        }

        Component.onCompleted:
        {
             treeView.model = Qt.binding(function()
             {
                 if (typeof theModel !== "undefined")
                 {
                     console.log("Model loaded");
                     return theModel;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     console.log("Couldn't load model");
                    return null;
                 }
             });
        }
    }
}
```

**TreeDelegate.qml**

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQml 2.0

Item
{
    id: item
    width : parent.width
    height: 25

    TextEdit
    {
        id: text1
        font.pixelSize: 14
        readOnly: true
        focus: false
        width : parent.width
        height: 25 * lineCount
        anchors.left: parent.left
        wrapMode: TextEdit.Wrap
        text: styleData.value
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are interested in [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-xmllistmodel-xmllistmodel.html) ? Also, I would remove the Component.onCompleted handler in main.qml, you already have the treeView.model property bound (you can check the value by doing `onModelChanged: console.log("model: ", model)` )

Comment: I'm not allowed to use something else than a treeView sadly. I'm actually doing this as a minimal working example to fix another kind of issue I have with someone else's code, so I have to reuse the same tools.

Comment: In that case I would place breakpoints in the code and step through to see if the program is doing what you want it to do. Or if that's not viable, add lot's of logging. I don't particularly see stuff that's wrong (except the rolenames should probably start with a lower-case)

Comment: btw, the code block with caption "domItem.cpp" contains DomModel code ;-)

Comment: Oof. Editing that asap.

EDIT : done.